# Angular cli library typescript paths don't work

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have an angular cli project, and created a new library:

```
ng g library test
```

Now, in the `tsconfig.json` file, I added the following `paths` options:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@scope/name": ["projects/test/src/public_api.ts"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

But now when I try to use it in the application:

```
import { SomeComponent } from '@scope/name';

@NgModule({
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I get the error:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module '@scope/name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a file. You just have a typo. It should be:

```
"@scope/name": ["projects/test/src/public-api.ts"]
```